# Why is Twilio Lookup V2 API is returning incorrect number

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-verify

We are using Twilio to send SMS messages in our C# application. We have been sending SMS messages to only US numbers, but now we want to send to other countries.

I have looked at using the Twilio Lookup API in order to get the mobile number plus country code.

When I tested the V1 version of the Lookup API, it worked as expected.
But the V2 version of the Lookup worked for US mobile numbers but for some reason, it added an extra "1" to the beginning of the international number.

For example (using 'n' in place of real mobile number):

V1 phonenumber correctly returned this: "+60nnnnnnnnn":  https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/60nnnnnnnnn

V2 phonenumber returned the number like this, extra '1' in front: "+160nnnnnnnnn" : https://lookups.twilio.com/v2/PhoneNumbers/60nnnnnnnnn

The Twilio docs say to use V2 for new development, but V2 is not working in my case.

Has anyone else experienced this? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I don't know any real Malaysian phone numbers so I just used some random numbers and got the expected result, not the US country code.
I used this Twilio CLI command: `twilio api:lookups:v2:phone-numbers:fetch --phone-number +6032xxxxxxx`

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, but can you try adding the `CountryCode` parameter to your requests, if that's feasible for your application?